# How to add segmented control on tableviewcell in iPhone

Tags: ios4

My requirement is when user clicks on tableviewcell, segmented control should appear on that particular cell. Is there something I need to do in didSelectrowAtindexPath? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can try to solve this using a custom UITableViewCell. Create a custom cell with a segmented control which would have it's valueChanged action in the class of your custom cell. When the user changes the segment, the action in your custom cell class would be called and you'd be able to handle it.